# Peewee MySQL problem after upgrade to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, python, mysql, 19.10

Since the 19.10 upgrade Python peewee can't talk to MySQL anymore:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured('MySQL driver not installed!')
peewee.ImproperlyConfigured: MySQL driver not installed!
```

But all requirements are installed: `peewee`, `mysqlclient`, `pysocks`

Also `libmysqlclient-dev, libmysqlclient21`

**Update:**

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Using Mariadb, which is running fine.

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.17 database server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

## Fixed by:

```
pip3 install pymysql
```

Apparently `mysqlclient` is not enough anymore.